# I am looking for how to use jquery to isolate the text within a specific nestled child of a html file. i do not understand what i am doing wrong

Tags: jquery, node.js, web-crawler

How can I isolate the text held within this class in this code? I want to get the value and the name string using jquery. I am currently using Node.js to web scrape this webpage with cheerio. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXY9r.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXY9r.png)

Comment: Hi welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question too add in the code you are using and any errors you get. But please never ever paste pictures of code, always paste text then format it as a code snippet

Answer (score 0):

maybe the below can help

can also use find

$('.trn-stat').find('.name')
$('.trn-stat').find('.value')

var name = $('.trn-stat > .name')
var value = $('.trn-stat > .value')

Comment: The problem is I want to be able to isolate the text within each .trn-stat class, as each one contains the same local classes...

Comment: just so i understand, you need to get a list of the stats and process each one by one? $('.trn-stat') will provide an array of the DOM objects. From there you can obtain the name and value for each block and perform some processing.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but the html file from which I am trying to isolate the text from each .name and .value class has one of each for each .trn-stat class and has multiple .trn-stat classes for each given parent class, ie .dtr-stats-card.last7 class and .dtr-stats-card pl-solo etc. I want to know how to get the text from each .name and .value class  within each .trn-stat class, within each of the parent class.